# When i import from a file, click the next and previous buttons it is exporting data to my file? is there something wrong with my action listeners?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

```
public AddressBookApp(){

    frame = new JFrame("Address Book");
    frame.setSize(500, 400);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBackground(Color.gray);
    panel.setLayout(null);

    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
    frame.setJMenuBar(menubar);
    JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
    menubar.add(file);
    JMenuItem insert = new JMenuItem("Import");
            file.add(insert);
            insert.addActionListener(this);
            JMenuItem export = new JMenuItem("Export");
            file.add(export);
            export.addActionListener(this);
            JMenuItem exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
            file.add(exit);
            exit.addActionListener(this);

    Font f = new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 10);
    btnadd = new JButton("Add");
    btnadd.setFont(f);
    btnadd.setBounds(200, 250, 80, 20);
    panel.add(btnadd);

    btnprev = new JButton("Previous");
    btnprev.setBounds(40, 250, 80, 20);
    btnprev.setFont(f);
    btnprev.addActionListener(this);
    panel.add(btnprev);

    btnnxt = new JButton("Next");
    btnnxt.setBounds(120, 250, 80, 20);
    btnnxt.setFont(f);
    btnnxt.addActionListener(this);
    panel.add(btnnxt);

    btndel = new JButton("Delete");
    btndel.setBounds(280, 250, 80, 20);
    btndel.setFont(f);
    panel.add(btndel);

    btnclear = new JButton("Clear");
    btnclear.setBounds(360, 250, 80, 20);
    btnclear.setFont(f);
    btnclear.addActionListener(this);
    panel.add(btnclear);

    txtname = new JTextField("");
    txtname.setBounds(210, 40, 160, 20);
    txtname.setFont(f);
    panel.add(txtname);

    txtnum = new JTextField("");
    txtnum.setBounds(210, 70, 160, 20);
    txtnum.setFont(f);
    panel.add(txtnum);

    txtmob = new JTextField("");
    txtmob.setBounds(210, 100, 160, 20);
    txtmob.setFont(f);
    panel.add(txtmob);

    txtadd1 = new JTextField("");
    txtadd1.setBounds(210, 130, 160, 20);
    txtadd1.setFont(f);
    panel.add(txtadd1);

    lblname = new JLabel("Name");
    lblname.setBounds(160, 40, 160, 20);
    lblname.setFont(f);
    panel.add(lblname);

    lblnum = new JLabel("Number");
    lblnum.setBounds(160, 70, 160, 20);
    lblnum.setFont(f);
    panel.add(lblnum);

    lblmob = new JLabel("Mobile");
    lblmob.setBounds(160, 100, 160, 20);
    lblmob.setFont(f);
    panel.add(lblmob);

    lbladd1 = new JLabel("Address ");
    lbladd1.setBounds(160, 130, 160, 20);
    lbladd1.setFont(f);
    panel.add(lbladd1);

}
 public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    AddressBookApp ab =  new AddressBookApp();
}

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
   {
   if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Exit"))
       System.exit(0);
   else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Import"))
   {
          importContacts();
   }
   else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Export"));
   {
          exportContacts();
   }      
   if (e.getSource() == btnnxt)
   {
          nextContact();
   }
   else if (e.getSource() == btnprev)
   {
          prevContact();
   }
   }
    public void importContacts()
    {

    try{
        BufferedReader fileSize = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("../files/example.buab"));
        BufferedReader importContacts = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("../files/example.buab"));
        int i = 0;
        String contacts;
        while (( fileSize.readLine()) !=null)
        {
             details.add(importContacts.readLine());
             i++;
        }
        fileSize.close();
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        for (x = 0, y = 0; x < details.size(); x++, y++) 
        {
        if (y == 4)
        {
            y = 0;
        }
        if (y == 0)
        {
            name.add(details.get(x));
        }
        if (y == 1)
        {
            phone.add(details.get(x));
        }
        if (y == 2)
        {
            mobile.add(details.get(x));
        }
        if (y == 3)
        {
            address.add(details.get(x));       
        }         
        } 
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)               
         {                       
             ioe.printStackTrace();                
         }                
            txtname.setText(name.get(0));                
            txtnum.setText(phone.get(0));               
            txtmob.setText(mobile.get(0));               
            txtadd1.setText(address.get(0));
    }

   public void exportContacts()
   {
   FileOutputStream file; 
   PrintStream out; 

   try {   file = new FileOutputStream("../files/example.buab", true);   
          out = new PrintStream(file);       
          out.println(txtname.getText());      
          out.println(txtnum.getText());     
          out.println(txtmob.getText());
          out.println(txtadd1.getText()); 

          System.err.println ("");                    
          out.close();              
       }            
          catch (Exception e)
                {                   
                 System.err.println ("Error in writing to file");          
                }
   }

    public void nextContact()
    {

       if(index < details.size() - 1)               
       {           

            index++; 


            txtname.setText(name.get(index));                
            txtnum.setText(phone.get(index));               
            txtmob.setText(mobile.get(index));               
            txtadd1.setText(address.get(index));            
       }                
       importContacts();
    }

    public void prevContact()
    {
    if (index > 0)               
     {                       
           index--;  


            txtname.setText(name.get(index));                
            txtnum.setText(phone.get(index));               
            txtmob.setText(mobile.get(index));               
            txtadd1.setText(address.get(index));               
     }           
     importContacts();

    }
```

}

Comment: Can you please phrase a proper question? The Title of the post is not the right place for the question. Also, SO is not a debugger.

Comment: really bad way to ask a question. make some effort and someone may respond with effort of their own.

Comment: tommmm, have you ever wondered what netiquette is about?

Answer (score 1):

From the code I see no reason, why it should export data after pressing the next or previous button. Don't forget to close the streams after reading.

Just for curiosity - I've seen a lot of partial solutions to this assignment from various new SO users - and they have in common, that the assignees *seems* to lack some basic OO knowledge. Who advised you to drop the contact details in separate lists rather then inventing a Contact class that holds all contact attributes and dropping contact objects in a single (sortable) list? Have you been forced to avoid classes or has your teacher simply left you alone, finding it out yourself?

Good luck anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the semicolon at the end of this line:

```
else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Export"));
```